# Converting an IEnumerable<dynamic> to array of arrays C#

Tags: c#

I have an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which I get from a dapper query which serialized using json.net gives as below..

```
[{"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"}]
```

I want the json in the below format..

```
[["ZoomIn","Zoom In"],
["ZoomOut","Zoom Out"],
["OriginalView","Original View"]]
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple snippet  using JavaScriptSerializer,

```
public class Friends
    {

        public List<FacebookFriend> data {get;set;}
    }

    public class FacebookFriend
    {

        public string id {get;set;}
        public string label{get;set;}
    }

    Friends facebookFriends = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Friends>(result);

    string json=
        @"{""data"":[{"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
            {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
            {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"}]}";


    Friends facebookFriends = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Friends>(json);

    foreach(var item in facebookFriends.data)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, label: {1}",item.id,item.label);
    }
```

Comment: The output has to be a json and I have IEnumerable<dynamic> and not strongly typed objects